# How do i call a javascript function to execute after another script ends

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to call function sumWH after the completion of the function sumMon1. Both functions get the text from labels, sum up their values, and update a counter label. The code that I have attempted to use to call sumHW after sumMon1 is below and does not work.

```
$.when(sumMon1()).done(function () {
    sumWH();
});
```

the sum functions look like this:

```
<script>
$.when(sumMon1()).done(function () {
    sumWH();
});

function sumWH() {
    alert(event.target);

    //Get Friday AM Out Value
    var a = parseInt($('[id$="lblWeek1FridayTotalHrs"]').val(), 10) || 0;
    //Get Friday AM IN Value
    var b = parseInt($('[id$="lblWeek2FridayTotalHrs"]').val(), 10) || 0;
    //Get Friday PM Out Value
    var c = parseInt($('[id$="lblWeek1SaturdayTotalHrs"]').val(), 10) || 0;
    //Get Friday AM IN VALUE
    var d = parseInt($('[id$="lblWeek2SaturdayTotalHrs"]').val(), 10) || 0;
    //Get Friday AM Out Value
    var e = parseInt($('[id$="lblWeek1SundayTotalHrs"]').val(), 10) || 0;
    //Get Friday AM IN Value
    var f = parseInt($('[id$="lblWeek2SundayTotalHrs"]').val(), 10) || 0;
    //Get Friday PM Out Value
    var g = parseFloat($('[id$="lblWeek1MondayTotalHrs"]').val(), 10);
    //Get Friday AM IN VALUE
    var h = parseInt($('[id$="lblWeek2MondayTotalHrs"]').val(), 10) || 0;
    //Get Friday AM Out Value
    var i = parseInt($('[id$="lblWeek1TuesdayTotalHrs"]').val(), 10) || 0;
    //Get Friday AM IN Value
    var j = parseInt($('[id$="lblWeek2TuesdayTotalHrs"]').val(), 10) || 0;
    //Get Friday PM Out Value
    var k = parseInt($('[id$="lblWeek2WednesdayTotalHrs"]').val(), 10) || 0;
    //Get Friday AM IN VALUE
    var l = parseInt($('[id$="lblWeek1WednesdayTotalHrs"]').val(), 10) || 0;
    //Get Friday AM Out Value
    var m = parseInt($('[id$="lblWeek2ThursdayTotalHrs"]').val(), 10) || 0;
    //Get Friday AM IN Value
    var n = parseInt($('[id$="lblWeek1ThursdayTotalHrs"]').val(), 10) || 0;
    var result = a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i + j + k + l + m + n;

    if (result > 0 && result < 81 && !isNaN(result)) {
        $('[id$="txtTotalHours"]').html(result);
    } else if (result == 0) {
        $('[id$="txtTotalHours"]').html(0);
    } else if (isNaN(result)) {
        $('[id$="txtTotalHours"]').html(result);
    }
}
</script>

 <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            sumMon1();
            $('[id$="txtWeek1MondayPM_OUT"], [id$="txtWeek1MondayAM_OUT"]').on("blur", function () {
                sumMon1();
            });
        });

        function sumMon1() {

            //Get Monday AM Out Value
            var Out2Dec = $('[id$="txtWeek1MondayAM_OUT"]').val();

            //split dec and whole AM OUT
            var OutAmDec = Out2Dec % 1;
            var OutAMWhole = Math.floor(Out2Dec);
            if (OutAMWhole < 12 && OutAMWhole != 0 && !isNaN(OutAMWhole)) {
                OutAMWhole += 12;
            }


            //Get Monday AM IN Value
            var In2Dec = $('[id$="txtWeek1MondayAM_IN"]').val();
            //split dec and whole AM IN
            var InAmDec = In2Dec % 1;
            var InAmWhole = Math.floor(In2Dec);

            //Get Monday PM Out Value
            var Out1Dec = $('[id$="txtWeek1MondayPM_OUT"]').val();
            //split dec and whole PM OUT
            var OutPmDec = Out1Dec % 1;
            var OutPMWhole = Math.floor(Out1Dec);
            if (OutAMWhole < 12 && OutAMWhole != 0 && !isNaN(OutAMWhole)) {
                OutPMWhole += 12;
            }

            //Get Monday AM IN VALUE
            var In1Dec = $('[id$="txtWeek1MondayPM_IN"]').val();
            //split dec and whole PM IN
            var InPmDec = In1Dec % 1;
            var InPMWhole = Math.floor(In1Dec);


            //calculate times
            var InAmVal = (InAmWhole * 60) + (InAmDec * 100);
            var OutAmVal = (OutAMWhole * 60) + (OutAmDec * 100);

            var InPmVal = (InPMWhole * 60) + (InPmDec * 100);
            var OutPmVal = (OutPMWhole * 60) + (OutPmDec * 100);


            var Difference = (OutAmVal - InAmVal) + (OutPmVal - InPmVal);
            var result = Difference / 60;
            //display result
            if (result > 0 && !isNaN(result)) {
                $('[id$="lblWeek1MondayTotalHrs"]').html(result.toFixed(2));
            } else {
                var value2 = (result.toFixed(2) * -1);
                $('[id$="lblWeek1MondayTotalHrs"]').html(value2);
            }

        }
</script>
```

The sum functions are located in separate script tags. sumMon1 is set to go on blur from a series of textboxes.

Is this there a way to make this function work or is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: Nothing asynchronous shown so you should be able to simply do `sumMon(); sumWH();`. If your code isn't working you need to provide a [mcve] and provide more specifics about actual problem and what is or isn't working as well as error status

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`jQuery.when` is for async functions.
async is something like `setInterval` or `jQuery.ajax`.
And except async stuff, JavaScript (Or almost any other languages as well) run codes from top to the bottom sequentially.

Your code is not using asynchronous things. so simply do

`sumMon();
sumWH();`

Comment: Would that go in this block?                                                                                                                               $(document).ready(function () {
            sumMon1();
            $('[id$="txtWeek1MondayPM_OUT"], [id$="txtWeek1MondayAM_OUT"]').on("blur", function () {
                sumMon1();
            });
        });

Comment: Wherever you have "sumMon();" change it to "sumMon();sumWH();"